# How to filter a grouped alphabetic listview in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a listview following the example of this project
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys where the list gets sorted alphabetically.

It works very well but when I now try to implement a search function it is giving me a bit of trouble. It works when I type the first letter and I succesfully get all the items with that letter but when I want to sort the items that has the same first letter the list remains the same as if i just typed the first letter.

So if there is two names starting with A, for example: Anna and Alice. If a user then writes A-n then anna will show up. If they write A-l, alice will show up.

This is what I have implemented:

```
searchBar.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(searchBar.Text);
searchBar.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(searchBar.Text);
FilterContacts(listview.ToString());
```

Class:

```
public class items
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string NameSort => Name[0].ToString();
}
```

When I gather info to my ObservableCollection:

```
public static ObservableCollection<CompanyViewModel<string, items>> groupedList { get; set; }
public static ObservableCollection<items> theClassItem { get; set; }

async Task loadItems()
    {
        var getNames = await phpApi.getNames();

        theClassItem = new ObservableCollection<items>();

            foreach (var lesitems in getNames["results"])
            {
                theClassItem.Add(new items()
                {
                    Name = lesitems["Name"].ToString()
                });

            }

            var sortedList = from gathereditems in theClassItem
            orderby gathereditems.Name
            group gathereditems by gathereditems.NameSort 
            into groupList
            select new CompanyViewModel<string, items>(groupList.Key, groupList);

            groupedList = new ObservableCollection<CompanyViewModel<string, items>>(sortedList);

            listview.ItemsSource = groupedList;

        }
```

Filter function:

```
private void FilterContacts(string filter)
    {
        listview.BeginRefresh();
        listview.ItemsSource = groupedList;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
        {

        }

        else {
            if (groupedList != null) //groupedList.Count != null 
            {
                listview.ItemsSource = groupedList.Where(x => x.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())));
            }
        }

        listview.EndRefresh();
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you just want the results which start with a certain letter or text and not containing it? Change this in your filter function `listview.ItemsSource = groupedList.Where(x => x.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())));` to `listview.ItemsSource = groupedList.Where(x => x.Any(p => p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter.ToLower())));` notice how I changed `Contains` to `StartsWith`

Comment: Yeah I want it to filter by the text you write. So if there is two names starting with A, for example: Anna and Alice. If a user then writes A-n then anna will show up. If they write A-l, alice will show up. I tried the code but the outcome is the same

Comment: Be sure to clean and rebuild etc. This shouldn't have the same outcome.

Comment: Very strange but the outcome seems to be the same. I tried to rebuild/clean and I also created another label just to see that the code is getting updated. But yeah the problem remains: When I write the first letter it sorts after that first letter but then afterwards nothing happens when i enter more letters. this `p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter.ToLower())` line is undermarked with a yellow line btw

Comment: And what does the yellow line say when you hover over it?

Comment: `StartsWith is culture-aware and missing a StringComparison argument`